# PHP creating a new object or use existing one if isset?

Tags: php, object, new-operator, ternary-operator, isset

Many times i find this redundant:

```
$found = $repo->findOneByCode($code);
$zone = isset($found) ? $found : new Zone();
```

Can anyone suggest a better way, similar to (not working):

```
$zone = $repo->findOneByCode($code) || new Zone();
```

**EDIT**: i can't modify `Zone` and `findOneByCode` as they are auto-generated classes and function by Doctrine ORM.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Extend the `findOneByCode()` method into one that returns the desired null object rather than `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you're using >= PHP 5.3**

```
$zone = $repo->findOneByCode($code) ?: new Zone();
```

**otherwise** maybe this is better? (still a bit ugly)...

```
if ( ! ($zone = $repo->findOneByCode($code))) {
    $zone = new Zone();
}
```

Assuming on failure, `$repo->findOneByCode()` returns a falsy value...

Comment: @jondavidjohn `findOneByCode()` is part of Doctrine ORM api, i have no control over it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a lazy singleton pattern. This is when there is only ever one instance of the class, but it doesn't get initialized until you try to use it.

Example: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/2010/02/php-5-3-lazy-singleton-class/

Comment: I can't modify "Zone" class because is auto-generated. And wrapping it seems a bit overkill...

Comment: Be careful with Singletons. They are generally frowned upon for introducing tight coupling and making code hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$zone = ($z = $repo->findOneByCode($code)) ? $z : new Zone();
```

Note, however, that this does not work *exactly* like using `isset()`. While using `isset()` will allow other falsey values other than `NULL` to pass through (such as `FALSE`), using `a ? b : c` will resolve to `c` **on all falsey values**.

Answer (score 0):

These two methods will also do the job:

```
$zone = $repo->findOneByCode($code) or $zone = new Zone();

($zone = $repo->findOneByCode($code)) || ($zone = new Zone());
```

Note that `or` and `&&` have different precedences and that is why we need the () in the second example. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php. The example there is:

```
// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;

var_dump($e, $f);
```

And the result:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

This is because `and` and `or` have lower precedence than `=` meaning the assignment will be done first. On the other side, `&&` and `||` have higher precedence than `=` meaning the logical operation will be done first, and its result assigned to the variable. That is why we cannot write:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) || die(...);
```

`$result` will hold the result of the logical operation (true or false). But when we write:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(...);
```

the assignment is done before the logical operation. And if it is not falsely value, the part after the `or` is cimpletely ignored.